# Azure AD B2C how to change the Token exp claim value

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

By default the JWT exp date is set to a month.  When I opened the policy in the azure portal it says that the token lifetime is set to 60 minutes, but is being ignored. I tried changing the values without luck.

How to create JWT with an expiration day of 1 hour?

Comment: How did you try to configure token lifetimes? Reffered to this document ?
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**AAD B2C Token lifetimes configuration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso)

> Access & ID token lifetimes (minutes): The lifetime of the OAuth 2.0
>   bearer token used to gain access to a protected resource.
>
> ```
> Default = 60 minutes.
> Minimum (inclusive) = 5 minutes.
> Maximum (inclusive) = 1440 minutes.
> ```
>
> Refresh token lifetime (days): The maximum time period before which a
>   refresh token can be used to acquire a new access or ID token (and
>   optionally, a new refresh token, if your application had been granted
>   the offline_access scope).
>
> ```
> Default = 14 days.
> Minimum (inclusive) = 1 day.
> Maximum (inclusive) = 90 days.
> ```
>
> Refresh token sliding window lifetime (days): After this time period
>   elapses the user is forced to re-authenticate, irrespective of the
>   validity period of the most recent refresh token acquired by the
>   application. It can only be provided if the switch is set to Bounded.
>   It needs to be greater than or equal to the Refresh token lifetime
>   (days) value. If the switch is set to Unbounded, you cannot provide a
>   specific value.
>
> ```
> Default = 90 days.
> Minimum (inclusive) = 1 day.
> Maximum (inclusive) = 365 days.
> ```

**How to :**

> 1. Follow these steps to navigate to the B2C features menu on the Azure portal.
> 2. Click Sign-up or sign-in policies. Note: You can use this feature on any policy type, not just on **Sign-up or sign-in policies**.
> 3. Open a policy by clicking it. For example, click on B2C_1_SiUpIn.
> 4. Click Edit at the top of the menu.
> 5. Click Token, session & single sign-on config.
> 6. Make your desired changes. Learn about available properties in subsequent sections.
> 7. Click OK.
> 8. Click Save on the top of the menu.

[image]

Comment: This has changed since the question was first answered. For me now it's `inside a policy >  properties (under Settings) > Token Lifetime section`.